# Highstock month dataGrouping with Jalali/Persian dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highstock `StockChart` which uses `Persian(Jalali)` dates.

I am using `dataGrouping` on days and months. Although dataGrouping is fine on `days`, `months` grouping is not working. Its because of the difference between Jalali and Christian months.

For example 1st of `January` begins on 10th of month `دی` of Jalali months. So when I have data from 1st of `دی` to 30th of `دی` (the whole month), I want `Highcharts` to show only one column for `دی` but instead it shows two columns. One for `آذر` (a month before `دی`) and one for `دی`. It's because it sees `December` before `January` (because of the 10 day difference).

Here's a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/SQwGT/9/

Its not a good example specially when most of you don't know Persian language, but it somehow demonstrates the issue.

How can I fix it? Is there a way I can tell `Highcharts` how to manage its months? Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a `PersianDate` class and implemented every single method in the class `Date` more importantly `set/get UTC Date/Month/...` methods. And I used:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        Date: PersianDate
    }
});
```

to change the `Date` class the `Highchart` uses. After that the chart knew which month started and ended in which days from the `UTC` Date format and the `dataGrouping` worked fine with `Jalali` months.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite default [approximation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation), and prepare your own.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My problem is not how the `dataGrouping` function works. I do not want to change the `average` to `sum`. When I use `month` grouping I want my data to be grouped from 10th of the first month to 10th of the second month, not the first day of every month. `approximation` takes a numeric array which in my case is the data between 1st of this month to the 1st of next month. I want that data to be from the 10th day. I hope I am clear enough